# How to get id of those persons who have matching month and year only in dob column

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

In my table, I have some records and they have some duplicate date of birth values, so I want the `id` of those people who have matching year and month only    .

I am getting output like this:

[image]

but my expectation is:

```
id   dob(column name of table bday)

1  1989-12
3  1989-12
4  1985-11
6  1985-11
```

MySQL Query #1:

```
SELECT id, dob
FROM bday
WHERE dob IN (
    SELECT dob
    FROM bday
    GROUP BY dob
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
)
```

MySQL Query #2:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from dob) FROM bday group by dob having count(*) >1
```

Here I am getting output like this:

```
id   dob(column name of table bday)
1    1989-12-22
3    1989-12-22
4    1985-11-27
6    1985-11-27
```

But I actually only want the year and month with the `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from date)
 FROM table group by date having count(*) >= 2
```

try this

```
select YEAR(date) AS 'year', MONTH(date) AS 'month' COUNT(*) c FROM table GROUP BY column HAVING c > 1
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: it's not working i need id dob column bco'z id refer that duplicate person so extracting making new colum like this i am getting output       extract(YEAR_MONTH from dob)    =198912 i will once again update my question please review this

Comment: Hi @mhmd i tried that too but it  showing error ( An alias was previously found. near c) ,infect my column data type is date still not getting required output

Answer (score 1):

[See this post](http://anasthecoder.blogspot.ae/2015/09/mysql-tips-and-tricks.html#get_all_ids_of_peoples_who_have_matching_year_and_month_only)

Answer:

```
SELECT 
id, DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') AS date_month
FROM users 
WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y-%m') IN 
(
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y-%m') AS date_month 
    FROM users  
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y-%m') 
    HAVING count(id) >1) ;
)
```

**Explanation:**

First thing you have to achieve is to

> "get all date and month of 'dob' column"

This can be achieved by grouping rows based on date_month extracted using the format construct.

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') AS date_month 
FROM bday 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d');
```

As per your question, Next is

> "peoples who have matching year and month only"

ie, group the above results with condition having more than one row. 
This can be achieved by adding the condition "HAVING count(id) > 1"

Now the query becomes

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') AS date_month 
FROM bday 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') 
HAVING count(id) >1);
```

This query returns all date_month where more than one person's dob falls.

Now your ultimate aim is to get

> " id of those peoples who have matching year and month only "

This can be achieved by wrapping this results in a sub query.
ie, you have to fetch all ids with date and month falls in the set of results extracted using the previous query

```
SELECT 
id, DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') AS date_month
FROM bday
WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') IN 
(
    SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') AS date_month 
    FROM bday 
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') 
    HAVING count(id) >1) ;
)
```

**My table structure**
[image: My table structure]

**Data in table**
[image: My entries]

**Query and results**
[image: Query and results]

Comment: Hello @lma thank's a lot it's working for me ,you are  brilliant